# Spark Accumulator throws a class cast exception when trying to count the number of records in the dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset, rdd

I am trying to count the number of records in my dataset. I am trying the below logic using accumulators.

```
    val accum = sc.longAccumulator("My_Accum")
    val fRDD = tempDS.rdd.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK).foreach(x=>{
      accum.add(1)
      x
    })

    val recordCount = accum.value

    println("record Count is : "+recordCount)
```

I am getting a class cast exception on line accum.add(1) as
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to packagename.CaseClassName.

With the same logic I am able to get the accumulator value in my previous step

Can someone please help me how to resolve this. Also is there any other way to count other than count() and accumulators.

Comment: see if changing 1L from 1 helps

Comment: this code works fine for me, spark 2.4 with scala 2.11

Comment: it worked in one scenario for me but when I try the same logic as it is, I am getting this error. I think when I try to do dataset.foreach or dataset.map it is not able to recognize the schema and is treating it as GenericRow instead of my case class

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is the accumulator, it seems that Spark can't convert your `DataFrame`, i.e. `Dataset[Row]` into a `Dataset[packagename.CaseClassName]` (which you don't show in your code).

Besides, this is a really unconventional way to count the number of rows, I would NOT recommend this. Fastest way is `.count` on your `Dataset`, using the `RDD` is slower in most cases

Comment: I am using Dataset[MyClass] and not dataframe. Also count is an expensive operation so I want to use accumulators